# ListView Item not updating (Some part of listItem is updating but not all) after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-listview, android-progressbar

I am using customised `ListView` in my application in which each row item of the `ListView` contains some `TextView`s, `ImageView` and a `ProgressBar`. After clicking an item in the `ListView` I remove that item from the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Now only `TextView`s and other `View`s are updating in my `ListView` but `ProgressBar` is not updating. Means I still see the complete progress instead of an empty progress.

But when I click on the last item of the list it goes properly (`ProgressBar` is also updating), but the middle item of the `ListView` is showing such behaviour. Please explain this behaviour

Thanks in advance